# How to replace Variable With Variable

Tags: replacement, variable

```
Clear[a, b, c];
a = c;    a =. ;    b = a;    b =.;    c = b;    c =.;
Print[a, b]
```

and the result is

> {a b}

but I want the result `{b a}` by using a Temp help. how is the code suppose to be?

Comment: Is this what you need? `Print[a, b] // Inactivate // Reverse // Activate`

Comment: i dont get it, the expample is i want to Give the value of A to Temp, Then give the Value of B to A, and C to B and the last Temp to C. so the result if i Print[A,B] its will result B,A . And also work if i input values

Comment: I don't think it makes sense unless a/b/c have values. Can you provide a small example?

Comment: yea, they have it

Comment: `{a, b, c} = {b, c, a};`?

Comment: Unclear what is wanted that would not induce infinite recursion. Maybe something like this (also suggested by @Kuba)? `In[277]:= x = 3;
y = 5;
{x, y} = {y, x};
{x, y}

Out[280]= {5, 3}`

Comment: @Kuba I think he wants `{a, b} = {b, a}` since I think `c` was just his temporary variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[a, b]
a := Defer[b]; b := Defer[a];
Print[a, b]
```

> ba

With values

```
Clear[a, b, c]
a = 1; b = 2;
c = a; a = b; b = c;
Print[a, b]
```

> 21

Comment: How to make its work if i input the variable with values

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the output the OP has in mind is possible within reasonable bounds of normal programming. If you want `a` to evaluate to `b` and `b` to evaluate to `a`, the evaluation chain will never end.

If you're only interested in the output, use `Defer`:

```
a = Defer[b];
b = Defer[a];    
Print[a, b]
```